# ¿Como crear trigger que actuallice los campos de una tabla con otra?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Esta es mi primera pregunta aquí, bueno al punto, para la clase de Bases de Datos II necesito crear un trigger en MySQL que al insertar datos en la tabla alumno se actualice también la tabla de respaldo_alumno, yo se que puede ser una pregunta quiza muy X pero agrdecería su ayuda:

```
CREATE TRRIGER alumupdate AFTER UPDATE ON alumno UPDATE respaldo_alumno SET nombre=UPDATE.NOMBRE,direccion=UPDATE.DIRECCION,codigo=UPDATE.CODIGO WHERE codigo=alumno.codigo
```

Este es el código de mi trigger, si me pueden orientar o decirme que le tengo que corregir lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que entiendo es que al insertar en alumnos,tambien se inserte en respaldo_alumnos,si es verdad, prueba este ejemplo en la version 5.6

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `alumupdate` AFTER INSERT ON `alumnos` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO respaldo_alumno (codigo, nombre, direccion)
VALUES (NEW.codigo, NEW.nombre, NEW.direccion);
END $$

DELIMITER ;

Antes crea las tablas correspondientes para que pueda funcionar el trigger,basicamente cuando insertes en Alumnos se vera reflejado automaticamente en respaldo_alumnos.

Saludos!

Comment: gracias por su ayuda... en si ese trigger que me muestras arriba ya lo tengo ,,lo que necesito es lo siguiente ejmplo si yo en la tabla alumo inserto de registro a marco con direccion las barcas #3322 y el codigo 123 se va a ejecutar el trigger anteriormente mostrado pero si yo actualizo el nombre = marco fabian direccion=rosales #2244 y codigo=54321 se actualicen los otros registros tambien

Comment: Hola que tal,antes que todo una disculpa por la tardanza al contestar,si entiendo bien, necesitaras otro trigger que actualize,uno que inserte y otro que actualice se me ocurre algo asi   DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER alumupdate2 AFTER update ON alumnos FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE respaldo_alumno SET nombre=NEW.nombre,direccion=NEW.direccion where codigo=NEW.codigo;
END $$

DELIMITER ;